# Extracting multiple substrings from a string in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, string, xslt, substring, xslt-1.0

Spent far too long on this seemingly impossible issue today, I'm at my wits end. Would appreciate any help, have search stackoverflow high and low.

I have a string I'm trying to manipulate with XSLT e.g.

'**man START red END woman START child END rabbit START goose END blue**'

I'm trying to extract all substrings between START and END, and concat into one new string.

So the resulting string should be:

'**red child goose**'

Thanks - Rob

Comment: Where does this string come from? A parameter? An input XML document? If so, please show it. Are you really limited to XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do not know where this string comes from, but assuming an input document like

**XML Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<input>man START red END woman START child END rabbit START goose END blue</input>
```

**XSLT Stylesheet**

Write a recursive named template that looks for occurrences of `START` and `END` in the string.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="input">
      <output>
          <xsl:call-template name="find-relevant-text">
              <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
          </xsl:call-template>
      </output>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="find-relevant-text">
        <xsl:param name="string"/>

        <xsl:if test="contains($string,'START')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($string,'START '),'END')"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="find-relevant-text">
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string,'END ')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>red child goose </output>
```

If you are concerned about the whitespace character at the end, use

```
<xsl:template name="find-relevant-text">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>

    <xsl:if test="contains($string,'START')">

        <xsl:variable name="relevant-part" select="substring-before(substring-after($string,'START '),' END')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="remainder" select="substring-after($string,'END ')"/>

        <xsl:value-of select="$relevant-part"/>
        <xsl:if test="contains($remainder,'START')">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:call-template name="find-relevant-text">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select="$remainder"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks a million Mathias, The string comes from the contents of an external HTML file, referenced within an XML document, that I have converted to a variable. I will put your solution into practice and get back with feedback asap. Many thanks for your response.

Comment: @RobMcG You are welcome. If you don't get it to work, please show this variable definition and the XML document - and I'm glad to help.

Comment: Thanks so much Mathias, that worked perfectly. Spent seven hours trying to figure that out yesterday :) ... really appreciate your help. Life saver. Thank you again.

Comment: @RobMcG You are welcome. Looking forward to your next question.